# How to speed up for loop subsetting a DataFrame by a given value in a column and applying a formula in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I was wondering whether there was a way to speed up this code:

```
alphas = []

origins = flows["OrigCodeNew"].unique()

for origin in origins:
    df = flows[flows["OrigCodeNew"] == origin]
    alpha = sum(df["DestSal"] ** gamma * df["Dist"] ** beta])
    alphas.append(1/alpha)

alphas = pd.DataFrame(zip(origins, alphas), columns = ["OrigCodeNew", "alpha"])
```

Where the input is a DataFrame of the form:

```
OrigCodeNew   Destination  DestSal Dist
A             C            20000   6
A             D            30000   8
A             E            25000   10 
A             F            35000   2
B             C            20000   7
B             D            30000   5
B             E            25000   20
B             F            35000   13
```

With an output:

```
OrigCodeNew  Alpha (example)
A            0.034
B            0.064
```

I know this is inefficient code and it could be sped up but I'm not sure how. I have been using this for a while and it works but I am trying to refactor code to make it more efficient. I have tried to figure out pandas.groupby with the agg function but haven't been able to figure out how to do it with this sort of equation yet. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide any sample data or expected outputs, so it is hard to answer this question.

Theoretically, you should be able to groupby and then use transform, which will assign the group value to each row in the group. If you are more comfortable using agg, you can calculate the group value and then join the original dataframe and the aggregates on 'OrigCodeNew'.

```
(
  flows
  .groupby('OrigCodeNew')
  .transform(alpha=lambda x: 1 / (sum(x.DestSal ** gamma * x.Dist ** beta)))
)
```

Comment: Thank you! Would .agg follow the same formula usage?

Comment: `agg` can also take a lambda function, as described in [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html)